# i want to validate radio buttons with javascript for a quiz what my code needs?

Tags: javascript

here is my code so far. i want to do this for one homework at my university and i am trying from yesterday to figure it out can anyone help me?

I have 5 questions and 3 answers for each one of them and i want to alert me when i hit the correct answer and when i hit the wrong ones to alert me so i can pick another one

```
<form name="game">
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div> Τι ύψος έχει το φράγμα της λίμνης; </br>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="200 μέτρα"> 200 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="125 μέτρα"> 125 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="83 μέτρα" id="right1"> 83 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="radio" value="Αποστολή">
      <p id="apant1"> </p>
      </div>
      <li>
        <div> Τι μήκος έχει το φράγμα της λίμνης; </br>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="500 μέτρα"> 500 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="83 μέτρα"> 83 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="200 μέτρα"> 200 μέτρα </br>
      <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">
      </div>
      <li>
        <div> Που βρίσκεται η " Κοιμωμένη των Αγράφων; </br>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="east"> Ανατολικά της Καρδίτσας </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="north"> Βόρεια της Καρδίτσας </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="west"> Δυτικά της Καρδίτσας </br>
      <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">
      </div>
      <li>
        <div> Ποιόν αιώνα χτίστηκε το Κάστρο του Φαναρίου; </br>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="15"> 15ο αιώνα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="12"> 12ο αιώνα </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="13"> 13o αιώνα </br>
      <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">
      </div>
      <li>
        <div> Πότε έγινε η απελευθέρωση της Καρδίτσας από τους Τούρκους? </br>
      </li>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="12 Απριλίου 1943"> 12 Απριλίου 1943 </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="12 Μαίου 1943"> 12 Μαιού 1943 </br>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="12 Μαρτίου 1943"> 12 Μαρτίου 1943 </br>
      <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">
      </div>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you at least tried something? Cause we're not here to serve you.

Comment: Easily available on internet, just learn it.

Comment: start learning about change event handling in javascript. If you have any related javascript written you need to post it or your chances of getting help are very poor

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that may help you.

Step1:-

First you set the element id for all correct answer radio button as "right" and for wrong answer set something else.

As  you have given in the first radio button
Ex:-

```
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="83 μέτρα" id="right"> 83 μέτρα   </br>
```

Step2:-

Then you write this jquery code:-

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("radio").click(function(){
        if($(this).id=="right"){
           alert("correct Answer !")
        }
        else{
           alert("Wrong Answer");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: @dervel7 Please accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: mm actually i wanted the validation to be with pure Javascript so maybe it will be a problem the jquery code 
thanks for ur effort though